# Simplifying in SymPy

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I use SymPy for symbolic calculations in Python and get e.g. an expression like

```
p**(-1.02)=-0.986873+3.62321E15*y**-.5
```

Is there a function in SymPy (e.g. in sympy.simplify?) to get something like

```
p= c + a*y
```

where c and a are constants
I tried the following result as below:

```
-1/p**1.02 + 3.62321e+15/y**0.5 - 0.986873
```

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense. Your first equation contradicts the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second equation appears to be the first rewritten to show negative exponents as positive and putting the power in the denominator. This is not linear in `y` so you cannot express the equation in the form `c + a*y` except as an approximation at a certain point.

So let's solve for `p` since that is what you are interested in:

```py
l, r = p**(-1.02), -0.986873+3.62321E15*y**-.5
il, ir = 1/l, 1/r
eq_p = root(ir, il.exp)
```

Getting a series approximation for `eq_p` can be done if you use Rationals instead of floats. You must also chose a value at which you want the approximation. Let's get a linear approximation near `y = 0.3` -- this corresponds to requesting `n=2`:

```py
>>> rational_eq_p = nsimplify(eq_p, rational=True)
>>> p_3_10 = series(rational_eq_p, y, 0.3, n=2).removeO(); str(p_3_10)
5.04570930197125e-16*y + 1.57426130221503e-16
```

You can verify that this is correct by checking to see that the value and slope at `y=0.3` are consistent:

```py
>>> p_3_10.subs(y,.3), eq_p.subs(y,0.3)
(3.08797409280641e-16, 3.08797409280641e-16)
>>> p_3_10.diff(y), eq_p.diff(y).subs(y,0.3)
(5.04570930197125e-16, 5.04570930197125e-16)
```

So now you have a linear approximation for your equation *at y = 0.3*